# In KRL, how do I detect if a variable is an array or hash?

Tags: krl

In KRL, I'd like to detect whether a variable is an array or hash so that I know if I need to use the decode or encode operator on it.  Is that possible?

I'd like to do something like this:

```
 my_var = var.is_array => var.decode() | my_var
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**
The best way to do this is with the **typeof()** operator.  This is new since the answer, but with the early interpretation of variables, the old way listed in the answer will no longer work.

Another useful operator for examining your data is **isnull()**

```
myHash.typeof() => "hash"
myArray.typeof() => "array"
...
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way that I have figured out how to detect the data structure type is by coercing to a string and then checking to see if the resulting pointer string contains the word 'array' or 'hash'.

***'One liner'***

```
myHashIsHash = "#{myHash}".match(re/hash/gi);
```

myHashIsHash will be true/1

**Example app built to demonstrate concept**

```
ruleset a60x547 {
  meta {
    name "detect-array-or-hash"
    description <<
      detect-array-or-hash
    >>
    author "Mike Grace"
    logging on
  }

  global {
    myHash = {
      "asking":"Mike Farmer",
      "question":"detect type"
    };
    myArray = [0,1,2,3];
  }

  rule detect_types {
    select when pageview ".*"
    pre {
      myHashIsArray = "#{myHash}".match(re/array/gi);
      myHashIsHash = "#{myHash}".match(re/hash/gi);
      myArrayIsArray = "#{myArray}".match(re/array/gi);
      myArrayIsHash = "#{myArray}".match(re/hash/gi);

      hashAsString = "#{myHash}";
      arrayAsString = "#{myArray}";
    }
    {
      notify("hash as string",hashAsString) with sticky = true;
      notify("array as string",arrayAsString) with sticky = true;

      notify("hash is array",myHashIsArray) with sticky = true;
      notify("hash is hash",myHashIsHash) with sticky = true;
      notify("array is array",myArrayIsArray) with sticky = true;
      notify("array is hash",myArrayIsHash) with sticky = true;
    }
  }
}
```

**Example app in action!**

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you.  One gotcha on this. If your variable is a string and the contents of that string are 'ARRAY...' or 'HASH...', then this doesn't work reliably.  I will check to see if there is a way to detect if a variable is a string.